# ngRoute is disturbing even if I using angular-route.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting continues error of ngRoute Error of module, even if I deleted from modules or added in modules.

```
<body ng-app="adminapp">  
       <div ng-controller="mainControl">
            <div ui-view>
            </div>
      </div>
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-idle.js"></script>
      <script src="js/asana-api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/angular-cookies.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

> in app.js

```
var app = angular.module('adminapp', ['ngRoute','ui.router','textAngular','ngIdle', 'ui.bootstrap', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ngCookies']);
```

> Error is

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=adminapp&p1=Error%…ttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fadminapp%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A368)
```

> Error Link is
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=adminapp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.11%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.11%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A417%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A251)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A494%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A237%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A85)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A254%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520p%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fwww.wtastudios.com%252Fwtaadmin%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:39:10%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:38:85)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:38:254%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:38:85)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:41:368)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Fwww.wtastudios.com%2Fwtaadmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:19:463

Comment: You are getting *what* errors? Error messages are there for a reason. They describe what went wrong. So *never* omit them when asking a question.

Comment: `'ui.router'` isn't included and needed there as well..

Comment: @PankajParkar yes I've mentioned it in the answer maybe thats the reason.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: update a question with whole error.. `[$injector:modulerr]` is common error tag.. we need whole line of error

Comment: question modified with error

Comment: For the development purposes I suggest you to use the unminified version all the JavaScript files. It gives you more description about errors and @mJunaidSalaat suggested, only include one file of each script.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ngRoute` so please remove `ui.router` like below

```
//removed 'ui.router' module from `adminapp` dependencies
var app = angular.module('adminapp', ['ngRoute','textAngular','ngIdle', 'ui.bootstrap', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ngCookies']);
```

and you also have added `angular-route` script two times. Consider removing one here.

```
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @SwamyReddy I cannot see a script for `LocalStorageModule`. Try removing it too maybe because this is the unknown module.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a template for ngRoute you can use it...

https://github.com/pankajofksms/Template/tree/master/Template1/src/main/resources/static

Comment: Use ng-view instead of ui-view..


And move <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to the bottom

Comment: made the chagnes as you sugested but still same error bro, removed cache too

Comment: did you look at my github demo

Comment: can you send me your plunkr

Comment: Did you download the cdn

Answer (score 0):

Your module depends on modules that you are requiring using `<script>` tag after the `<script>` tag that is loading your module.
Move

```
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To the bottom:

```
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-idle.js"></script>
  <script src="js/asana-api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, I see modules like ui.bootstrap but I don't see where you are requiring their script file.

Comment: I had moved it to the bottom, related script tag not mentioned here, because there are plenty of script tags,

Still same error

Comment: Try to drop everything in the module dependencies array and add them back one at a time to zoom in on the problematic one, or click on the link in the console next to the error message, and follow the path to find the problematic module

Comment: I added that errorlink in question now, can you please check

Comment: Tracking the path of the error leads to "Module 'ngRoute' is not available" - are you sure you are not getting 404 for the angular-route.min.js?

Comment: No not getting any error, I can see the code in the file